# Firestore schema migration between projects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase project which basically have two environments: **Staging** and **Production**. The way I organized them is by creating different Firebase projects. Each of my projects uses **[Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)** and **[Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore)**. Except for that, I have each of the projects associated with a specific GIT branch. Both of the branches are integrated into CI/CD pipeline in [**Google Cloud Build**](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/).

So, in order to make it absolutely clear, I will share a simple diagram:

[image]

As you can see, I have the source code for the cloud functions under source control and there's nothing to worry about there. The issue comes in when I have the following situation:

1. A Firestore schema change is present on **Staging**
2. Cloud function (on **Staging**) is adjusted to the new schema.
3. Merge **staging** branch into **production**.
4. Due to the old Firestore schema on **production**, the new functions there won't work as expected.

In order to work around it, I need to manually go to the **production** Firestore instance and adjust the schema there (there's a risk to mess up production data).

In the perfect case, I would have that operation automated and existing project data would be adjusted to a new schema which comes in dynamically after merge.

Is that possible somehow? Something like [migrations in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Firestore is schema-less - documents have no enforced schema.  Code is able to write whatever fields it wants at any time that it wants.  (For web and mobile clients, this is gated by security rules, but for backend code, there are no restrictions.)  As such, there is no such thing as a formal migration in Cloud Firestore.

The "schema" of your documents is effectively defined by your code that reads and writes those documents.  This means that migrating a data to a new format means that you're going to have to write code to perform the required changes.  There is really no easy way around this.  All you can really do is design your updates so that they are not disruptive to existing code when it comes time to move them to another environment.  This means your code should be resilient to breaking changes, or simply do not perform breaking changes until *after* all code has been updated to deal with those changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Google Cloud to download an archive of the Firestore data. Run a migration script yourself on the archive, and then upload the archive to restore your Firestore database.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import

Google Cloud gives you a lot of command line access for managing your Firestore service.

```
// manage indexes
gcloud firestore indexes

// export all data to a bucket
gcloud firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]

// import data from a bucket
gcloud firestore import gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[filename]

// manage admin "functions" currently running (i.e. kill long processes)
gcloud firestore operations
```

To download/upload your JSON archive from Google Cloud buckets

```
// list files in a bucket
gsutil ls gs://[BUCKET_NAME]

// download
gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[filename] .

// upload
gsutil cp [filename] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[filename]
```

Once you setup Google Cloud to be accessible from your build scripts. It's possible to automate data migration scripts to download, transform and then upload data.

It's recommended to maintain a "migrations" document in your Firestore so you can track which reversion of the migration needs to be done.

To avoid heavy migration tasks try adding a "version" property to documents, and then use the converter callbacks on the query builder to mutate data to the latest schema on "client side". While this won't help you handle changes with Firestore rules or functions. It's often easier to make tiny changes that are mostly cosmetic.